# How can I get A1 cell from a 97/03 Excel document with OleDB?

Tags: c#, excel, oledb

I've got a Excel 97/03 document that has "blabla" in its A1 cell in sheet "Sheet1". I thought the following should be able to extract it:

```
      string con = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=Book1.xls;" + @"Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;'";
      using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(con))
      {
        connection.Open();

        OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter("Select * From [Sheet1$]", connection);

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);

        dynamic cellA1 = dt.Rows[0][0].ToString();
```

But cellA1 is empty (""). Anyone know how to fix this, I should be able to treat it as a database and get cells from it?

Comment: did you try to point the file with complete path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"HDR=Yes;" indicates that the first row contains columnnames, not data. "HDR=No;" indicates the opposite. maybe thats the issue.

Answer (score 1):

The datatable is using the first row of data as its headers, to access the A1 cell simply use the name of the first column:

```
dynamic cellA1 = dt.Columns[0].ToString();
```